# What is a meta consensus?

Tags: discussion, meta

How many votes does it take to be a consensus? And what is the vote ratio needed?

The accepted answer will A. Abide by the rules for consensus it answered with and B. Have the most upvotes.

Comment: What practical reason do you have for asking? Such a broad question with potentially huge ramifications sets alarm bells ringing in my head.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah looking back more awake I realize how bad an idea that is.

Answer (score 3):

**Consensus simply means "general agreement."** There is no specific quantity of upvotes or downvotes that you can use to measure it, because if we change our minds later, the vote count will no longer reflect the consensus.

Votes can help us gauge the consensus of the community, but they do not necessarily represent it.

Comment: I've never thought of it this way:  The consensus is *not* defined by the meta, but is rather defined in all of our heads.  Meta is simply a method of communicating ideas to change each other's heads.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yeah. We've changed our minds before. One example is whether REPL is allowed. It wasn't generally allowed when I joined, but then it was changed to be counted as a separate language. Input consensus has changed as well, as Python 2's `raw_input()` was required instead of `input()` for a while.

Answer (score -3):

## 5 net votes and double the upvotes

I can't find a meta post about this, but this is fairly established and I don't think it has been changed.

If a meta post has a score of 5 (upvotes - downvotes) and the amount of upvotes is at least double the amount of downvotes, it has reached consensus.

Comment: I don't think there's anything supporting that specific quantity.

Comment: A quick search on meta shows multiple results for the terms "5 net votes".

Comment: @mbomb007 That particular standard comes form [loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/31716), where they wrote: `the loophole described in any answer which is at +5 or above and has at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes may be taken to be deemed to be unacceptable to the community`. However, that applies to just that question, so I don't think it's wise to make that a standard across meta.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Agreed.